# jQuery .load() not working inside another loaded content by jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading pages of the site in a div using jQuery load function. When i click on the top navigation, all pages are loading fine. But i have sub page links which are located inside the loaded content, when i click it is loading separately. Here is my code.

```
<ul class="top-navigation">
<li><a class="page-link" href="page1.html">Link1</a></li>
<li><a class="page-link" href="page2.html">Link2</a></li>
<li><a class="page-link" href="page3.html">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="page-content"></div>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$(".page-link").click(function(){
            var page_link = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#page-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#page-content').load(page_link, function(){
            $('#page-content').fadeIn('slow');
        });
});
</script>
```

contents of page1.html:

```
some page contents
<a class="page-link" href="sub-page1.html">Sub page</a>
```

i even tried to load the main js using `$.getScript()` but nothing works.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look into event delegation http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
your selector function would change to `$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function(){...`

Comment: Nope. It's not working. I also tried `.bind()` both not working.

Comment: This will work, i missed out something when i try at the first time. Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the elements didn't exist in the DOM when you bound them. Change the way you are binding to the elements.

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-link", function(){...
```

This will bind to existing as well as newly created elements on the page.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You're great xCNPx! something i missed when i tried the last time with binding method. Thanks a lot, it works.

Answer (score 1):

OK Now just replace with this

```
<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="sub-page1.html">Sub page</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page-link").click(function(){
        var page_link = $(this).attr("data-href");
        $('#page-content').load(page_link);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. i don't see any difference from the first code but either didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry Luigi I'm newbiew :)

Comment: @devdarsh I think the page that u try load is return 404 error (Not Found) check the console.log in your browser and tell me what u see or try to defining full url like `http//localhost/aaaa/bbb/ccc/sub-page1.html`

Comment: The page is loading but not inside the `div#page-content` it is loading in a new page when i am use `href="http://localhost/test19/sub-page1.html"`

Comment: @user3349436 Not problem, just keep that on mind to avoid down votes in the future.

Comment: @user3349436 when i use your code like `href="javascript:void(0)"` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: you dont read my post before properly check `href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="sub-page1.html"`

Comment: href attribute must be set to javascript:void(0) and replace the target page with data-href like this : `href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="sub-page1.html"`

Comment: do u have to try copy all of my code and replace it with yours?

btw do u have defined the #page-content I mean like `<div id="page-content"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-href="sub-page1.html">Sub page</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".page-link").click(function(){
            var page_link = $(this).attr("data-href");
            $('#page-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#page-content').load(page_link, function(){
                    $('#page-content').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In the main page :

```
<script>
$(".page-link").click(function(){

        var page_link = $(this).attr("href");
        $('#page-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#page-content').load(page_link, function(){
            $('#page-content').fadeIn('slow');
});

</script>
```

In the sub page :

```
<a class="page-link2" href="javascript:void(0);" loc="sub-page1.html">Sub page</a>

<script>
$(".page-link2").click(function(){

        var page_link = $(this).attr("loc");
        $('#page-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){

                $('#page-content').html("");
                $('#page-content').load(page_link, function(){

                        $('#page-content').fadeIn('slow');
                });
        });
});
</script>
```